# How can I use pipe ( | ) in Windows CMD title without quotes?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I'm playing with the bash scripts and I'm wondering how can I use the pipe symbol in title? I tried `title "|"` but the quotes are in the title too. Is there any other way I can make this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape the pipe `|` character with the `^` character:

```
C:\Windows\System32> title HELLO ^| WORLD
```

Output:

[image: Output of command "title HELLO ^| WORLD"]